# tests and database_cleaner for multiple databases

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

We have a Mailbox model which uses a secondary DB to which another mail app also connects. This is called using

```
establish_connection :mail_database
```

Now, I suppose I could attempt to wrap that in an `if` statement so it uses a different connection for the test environment, but I'm wondering how I could keep this database clean, preferably using database_cleaner which we already use for the 'regular' database.

I hope someone can nudge me in the right direction.

Comment: I hope you come up with a solution the last year we were dealing with this issue and it took hundres of try and error iterations, and at the end the solution was a completely messy hack.

Comment: @fguillen could you go into detail? Happy to hear how you did it

Comment: As I said it was a messy hack very difficult to remember, now I'm seeing the actual state of the project and I'm seeing they just finished adding a `test_helper.rb` method with a lot of `ModelName.destroy_all` :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have a rails3.2.10 application tested with rspec (2.12.0) and using database_cleaner (0.9.1 f4b44bb) having two database connections for mysql.

These are set in the *database.yml* something like:

```
test:
  ...
  database: my_app_test

test_my_second_connection:
  ...
  database: my_second_connection_test
```

The second database is connected in the model class with establish connection.

I was able to use the following settings in my *spec/spec_helper.rb* file according to the [manual of database_cleaner](https://github.com/bmabey/database_cleaner) :

```
require 'database_cleaner'

RSpec.configure do |config|

  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
    DatabaseCleaner[:active_record,{:connection => :test_my_second_connection}].strategy = :transaction
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
    DatabaseCleaner[:active_record,{:connection => :test_my_second_connection}].start
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
    DatabaseCleaner[:active_record,{:connection => :test_my_second_connection}].clean
  end

end
```

Additionally I have to use for some parts of the test suite non-transactional fixtures. So I had to add the meta information *:db_truncate => true* in my specs and the settings like this in order to change the strategy in test run:

```
config.before(:suite) do
  DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
  DatabaseCleaner[:active_record,{:connection => :test_my_second_connection}].strategy = :transaction
end

config.before(:each) do
  if example.metadata[:db_truncation]
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
    DatabaseCleaner[:active_record,{:connection => :test_my_second_connection}].strategy = :truncation
  else
    DatabaseCleaner.start
    DatabaseCleaner[:active_record,{:connection => :test_my_second_connection}].start
  end
end

config.after(:each) do
  DatabaseCleaner.clean
  DatabaseCleaner[:active_record,{:connection => :test_my_second_connection}].clean
  if example.metadata[:db_truncation]
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
    DatabaseCleaner[:active_record,{:connection => :test_my_second_connection}].strategy = :transaction
  end
end
```

Comment: A colleague had already found this, but it is indeed the solution. Thank you

Comment: I have the same situation (on Rails 3.2.12 and Rspec 2.14.7) with a connection to a second database in one of my models. When I set up DatabaseCleaner this way it seems that ALL my models attempt to connect to the second database, and of course things fail because tables are not present in the second database

Comment: @ChristerFernstrom Any luck solving that?

Comment: I ended up following the black magic here: https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner/issues/245

Answer (score 2):

```
****set database to clean by database cleaner in rails:-****
config.before(:suite) do
   DatabaseCleaner[:active_record, :connection => :test].clean_with(:truncation)
end

config.before(:each) do
  DatabaseCleaner[:active_record, :connection => :test].strategy = :transaction
end

config.before(:each) do
  DatabaseCleaner[:active_record, :connection => :test].start
end

config.after(:each) do
  DatabaseCleaner[:active_record, :connection => :test].clean
end
```